# ASP Ajax insert doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am working with ASP and i want to insert some data to the database without refreshing the page, thus using ajax.
But for some reason, which i cant identify, the data doesn't get inserted.

my index.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
    <a href="#" id="btnInsert" onclick="insertData()">INSERT</a>

    <script>
        function insertData() {
            var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            var description = document.getElementById("txtDesc").value;
            alert(name + description);
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insertAjax.aspx/Insert",
                    data: "{'name':'" + name + "','description':'" + description + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () { alert("Inserted"); },
                    error: function () { alert("Not inserted"); }
                });
        }

    </script>
```

insertAjax.aspx

```
public partial class insertAjax : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Insert(string name, string description) {
            using (ProductDataContext db = new ProductDataContext()) {
                Product dt = new Product();
                dt.Name = name;
                dt.Description = description;
                db.Products.InsertOnSubmit(dt);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }

    }
```

Product.dbml (using linq to SQL):

```
ID int (primary key, auto increment)
Name varchar(255)
Description varchar(255)
```

Comment: add `[WebMethod]` attribute to your method

Comment: Still doesnt do anything, im suspecting i didnt do the ajax function correctly but cant tell im in the process of learning...

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtName").value` should also produce invalid result - you have to set a static ID `ClientIDMode="Static` or  get the server ID `document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID%>')`

Comment: does your `alert("Inserted / Not")` show up?

Comment: no, i dont get that alert

Comment: have you checked your browser console for errors? Checked your network tab to see the HTTP status and response from the server? Set any breakpoints in the C# code to see if it's hitting the method and passing the parameters? Do some basic debugging and report the issues, then it'll be much easier for people to help you. If you don't even see the alert, there's probably a JS error, as fubo suggests. Checking the browser console should be the **first** thing you do in this kind of situation.

Comment: do you get that `alert(name + description);` alert?

Comment: i get the name + description alert and it is correct, but not the success/error ones

Comment: I get this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
    at insertData (Index.aspx:32)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Index.aspx:25)

Comment: sounds like maybe you didn't include jQuery in your page?

Comment: ok, i included jquery,now i get he alert'not inserted'and this error in console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 "Internal Server Error" means a server-side error. So, like I mentioned already, you need to set breakpoints and debug on the server side to see what is going wrong. Also if your project has got error handling routines, check your exception logs.

Comment: How would be the best approach for this? -i have a local SQL server, i use MS SQL management studio to make tables, etc...

Comment: no...debug your C# code in Visual Studio. Nothing to do with SQL Server. It's the C# code which is throwing an exception, probably somewhere in the Insert method.